# get error when set X-FRAME-OPTIONS in Apache HTTP Server 2.2

Tags: cross-domain, x-frame-options

Got below issue when I trying to add below code into httpd.conf file tail:

```
#iframe config
Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM http://xxxx
```

> Syntax error on line 489 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software
>   Foundation/Ap ache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid command 'Header',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included  in the server
>   configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add/uncomment below loading command

   ```
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
   ```
2. Change the line to below

   ```
    #Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://xxxxxx"
    #Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As the httpd.conf file accept name value pair format parameters, the value must be surround with double quote.

Like:

```
Header set x-frame-options "DENY"
```